# How to get Sphinx to recognize a module in the virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-poetry

I am writing python software using Python 3.11.3 and am documenting the code with Sphinx, specifically sphinx-build version 7.0.1.  I have been updating the sphinx documentation with no problem, each time I added a class or function; however, I just added a method that required the use of the `xmltodict` module which I installed to my virtual environment with `poetry`.  I have confirmed that the module shows up in my `pyproject.toml` file and also checked inside my `.venv` directory to confirm it was installed there.  However, when I run the command `sphinx-build -b source build` from my terminal, while in my virtual environment, the build fails, and I get the following WARNING.  `` WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'read_files.ReadKeyWords' from modue 'py_util_lib`; the following exception was raised: No module named 'xmltodict' ``.  As I mentioned, `xmltodict` does exist, and it is installed in the virtual environment I am running.  How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Check https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2390

Comment: @PepeNO Thank you for sharing this link with me, but I do not think that the issue the author was having is the one i am having.